# Getting Youtube videos using RecyclerView and cardView with Firebase in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, youtube, android-recyclerview, youtube-api

I have been working on an android project in which I have used **YouTube** API and **Firebase** as a database, I also used **recyclerView** in it but my videos from Firebase database are not showing in the application, I have implemented it correctly I guess but there is something wrong with it, please help.

> I am using Android Studio

**YouTube Firebase Adapter java class:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube_videos);
        YDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("youT");
        YouRecycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.Youtube_recycler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post2youtube, YoutubeViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post2youtube, YoutubeViewHolder>(

            post2youtube.class,
            R.layout.youtube_videos_card,
            YoutubeViewHolder.class,
            YDatabaseReference
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(YoutubeViewHolder viewHolder, post2youtube model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setYoutube(model.getYoutubing());
        }

    };

            YouRecycler.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class YoutubeViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder {
        View yView;

        public YoutubeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            yView = itemView;
        }
        public void setYoutube(final String youtubing){
            final YouTubePlayerView youPlay = (YouTubePlayerView) yView.findViewById(R.id.youtuber);
            youPlay.initialize("SOME KEY",
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubing);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                            YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                        }
                    });
        }
```

**Getter and setters class :**

```
public class post2youtube {
    private String youtubing;

    public post2youtube(){

    }

    public post2youtube(String youtubing) {
        this.youtubing = youtubing;
    }

    public String getYoutubing() {
        return youtubing;
    }

    public void setYoutubing(String youtubing) {
        this.youtubing = youtubing;
    }

}
```

**RecyclerView xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Youtube_recycler"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CardView xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtuber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @Mr.Rebot can you please help me here sir.